# Correctly setting date.timezone on Windows 7 for PHP 5.4.35 binary only install

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing unit tests for a series of PHP classes in NetBeans (testing with PHPUnit).

These classes rely on a nusoap script that I don't want to mock.

When I run tests that rely on nusoap as a dependency, I get the seemingly common "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone" error for this method in the nusoap script:

```
function getmicrotime() {
        if (function_exists('gettimeofday')) {
            $tod = gettimeofday();
            $sec = $tod['sec'];
            $usec = $tod['usec'];
        } else {
            $sec = time();
            $usec = 0;
        }
        return strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $sec) . '.' . sprintf('%06d', $usec);
    }
```

So, I have gone into my php.ini file and added:

```
[Date]  
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions ; 
; http://php.net/date.timezone 
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

I am only using PHP binaries. There is no web instance so there is only 1 ini file to modify, as far as I know.

When I rerun these tests I get errors from PHPUnit right away and no tests run. If I remove the edit to the ini file my tests run normally. "Normally" is defined as the tests return a failure with the same timezone error

Many of the other answers around the web suggest editing the ini file in two places, one for the web and one for the CLI. However, since I have only 1 ini file, I am not sure what else I need to modify in order to get the time zone correctly recognized.

How, on a Windows 7 machine with PHP 5.4.35 binaries installed (no IIS at all), would I make this work? I've also tried adding `date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );` to the nusoap script, but this seemingly had no effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a red herring, and a tough one to find too.

I went back to basics and dug around in my PHP.INI file and discovered I was using the test/prod version, so I decided to try the development version.

Running the tests in both NetBeans and the CLI, I was now able to see the "real" root cause, which was related to the class I was testing. There's just no information at all displayed to the user unless configured in PHP.INI.